# Youtube Cookies are not blocked by OneTrust auto-blocking script

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, one-trust

I am loading a script from Youtube on page load, which loads the script and creates some cookies, which are needed from Youtube.

Now, I have implemented OneTrust to work on cookies based on user consent. In Onetrust, there is a config to block any cookies to be created before any user consent. Here, other cookies are getting blocked except Youtube cookies. I am looking for any reason as if why Youtube cookies are created even before the user gives consent.

Any pointers would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1- You must enable automatically block known tracking technologies before publishing:

[image]

2- Make sure you implemented the script before any other scripts into the "head" section of the HTML template. If you integrate it via GTM, make sure OneTrust script fired first.